# Java Swing Drag and Drop with popup dialog

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop

I want the following behavior in a Java Swing application:

1. User drags and drops an icon.
2. User is prompted with a modal dialog if other icons should also be operated upon.
3. After the user chooses YES, NO, or CANCEL (or closes the dialog), Java begins operating on (copying/moving) the icons (or on cancel/close does nothing).

Within `TransferHandler.canImport()` I have visibility to the drop target but not to the icon.

Within `TransferHandler.exportDone()` I have visibility to the icon but not to the drop target.

Within `TransferHandler.importData()` I have visibility to both, but by then it's too late since if I'm performing a `TransferHandler.MOVE` then `TransferHandler.exportDone()` has already removed the icon.

Is the behavior I mentioned above possible using Java Swing?  If so, what version of the JDK/JRE do I need to use and how do I implement it?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand the question at all. It sounds like the user drags and drops something, and after a prompt, Java drags and drops other things all by itself?

Comment: I'll clarify the question - I want to move/copy the icons, not necessarily drag and drop them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to be able to possibly drag-and-drop items, as well as move/copy them programatically, you need to make sure you have a proper *model* set up which backs the *view*.  This means you shouldn't be coding your business logic directly into the GUI code.  The model should be simple and independent, focusing on the actual task of managing the data.  In your case, you it sounds like you just need to hold some collections of objects and provide methods which move/copy objects from one collection to the other.  The code which does this is called the *controller* (MVC - pardon me if you are already familiar with this pattern).  The controller will then update the GUI to reflect the changes.  Similarly, your drag-and-drop will trigger a controller action which performs a similar action on the model.

Comment: Thanks for the clear and concise answer.  I was thinking much along the same lines once I dug deep enough into the TransferHandler and Transferable documentation/JavaDoc.  The problem I'm having is one with timing (and with side effects) in the controller/view layer as affected by the current design which operates on the AWT event thread.

Comment: Best practise states the model should be thread-safe, but if it's only modified from the EDT then you shouldn't have any problems if it isn't.  You obviously know about the EDT rules.  I would need specific examples if you need further help.

Comment: Thanks again for your excellent answer!  In hindsight the codebase I fixed was very thread-unsafe, and by following the Java Tutorial documentation & your guidance I was able to refactor many classes and mostly follow an MVC pattern.

Today I'm investigating thread safety pertaining to displaying a confirmation prompt (dialog) in response to the drag-and-drop MOVE action, which seems to require canceling the action and properly following an MVC pattern.

Comment: I'm glad to hear this is still helping after so many years! In the case of your confirmation prompt, you may choose to hold a lock while waiting on the user's decision, unless it's critical that other threads can continue to work with the backing data quickly. At that point, you would indeed choose to abort and try again. When retrying, you'd need to get the lock again and check that the item in question is still in the same state as before. If your internal model already handles locking at the controller level, then the latter option is super easy.